# ubuntu-16.04.2 lenovo-ideapad-110-14isk display-screen

Tags: lenovo

I have Lenovo ideapad 110-14ISK, Machine Type Model: 80UC004RIH, previously it was dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04.02 and Window 7 and was working fine.

But suddenly one day when automatic Ubuntu update happen, laptop screen show black during boot-up also but I can hear that Ubuntu was started from laptop speaker sound but laptop screen was black.

After that i tried to connect external monitor with HDMI port and show that external monitor shows both Ubuntu and Window show display on external monitor but not on Laptop screen.

After that I did some experiment and concluded following step to may  my scree does not have damage problem  :

1) I re-installed Ubuntu 16.04.2.
2) Laptop screen working fine and shows display. This means it does not have screen issue.
3) Then I unpate my Ubuntu to higher version to 16.04.3 or higher.
4) Update done.
5) Restart laptop.
6) After restart scree does not show display.

I do not know what is the problem.

Currently i am running re-installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 version on my laptop.
Because of this issue Window7/10 does not show any display on laptop screen.

Please suggest what can be the problem and solution for this so that i can run both Ubuntu upgraded version and Window 7/10 also.

Thanks for your cooperation.